# How to stop everything on canvas from moving up using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm making a simple maths game using `tkinter` and am having some problems all the elements on the screen moving upwards.

So I have some code that creates screen A with a canvas. An image in the back ground and some buttons and text. When a button is pressed the screen is changed, another button is pressed it returns back to screen A by clearing the canvas and redrawing each element back on. I've tried to changing the anchor around but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

**The canvas looks like this after the return button is pressed**

[image: The canvas looks like this after the return button is pressed]

The first time the screen is visited it looks as it should.

Thank you :) Any help would be much appreciated

```
def showendscreen(self,returned):
    self.clearcanvas()

    if returned==False:
        self.newhighscore=checkifhighscore(self.mode)
        self.pictures=Pictures()
        if self.newhighscore == True:
            self.endtext="          congratulations \n you've got a new highscore!!"
            self.photo=self.pictures.congrats
        elif self.newhighscore==False:
            self.endtext = "Unlucky, keep practicing!"
        elif self.newhighscore == "same":
            self.photo=self.pictures.happy
            self.endtext="well done, you got your personal best again!"

    self.image1=Image.open(self.photo)
    (self.w,self.h)=self.image1.size
    self.image1a=ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image1)
    self.item1=self.canvas.create_image(self.w/2,self.h/2, image=self.image1a, anchor="center")
    self.canvas.create_text(self.w/2,50,fill="purple",font="Purisa 40 bold",anchor='center',text=self.endtext)
    self.canvas.create_text(self.w/2,600,fill="purple",font="Purisa 40 bold",anchor='n',text="You scored: "+ str(self.countq))
    self.canvas.grid()
    self.image1.close()
    self.btn3=tk.Button(root, width=18, height =1,text="Questions Answered", font = "Purisa 20",command=self.questionsanswered)
    self.btn3_window = self.canvas.create_window(((self.w/2)-150),(self.h/2)+3 ,anchor="center", window=self.btn3)    
    self.btn4=tk.Button(root, width=18, height =1,text="Scoreboard",font = "Purisa 20",command=self.scoreboard)
    self.btn4_window = self.canvas.create_window(((self.w/2)+150),(self.h/2)+3 ,anchor="center", window=self.btn4)
    self.btn5=tk.Button(root, width=18, height =1,text="My Progress",font = "Purisa 20", command = self.progress)
    self.btn5_window = self.canvas.create_window(((self.w/2)),(self.h/2)+60 ,anchor="center", window=self.btn5)
    self.btn6=tk.Button(root, width=10, height=1, text="Restart", font ="Purisa 15", command = restartgame)
    self.btn6_window=self.canvas.create_window(((self.w/2)),(self.h/2)+120 ,anchor="center", window=self.btn6)
    self.canvas.grid()
def clearcanvas(self): self.canvas.delete('all')
```

Button that reruns above function:

```
self.backbutton=tk.Button(root,image=self.returnb, command= lambda: self.showendscreen(True), anchor="nw") 
self.backbutton_window = self.canvas.create_window(10,60,anchor="nw", window=self.backbutton)
```

Comment: It would help if you created a proper [mcve]. Also, it would help if you could duplicate the problem without the need to use images. My guess is that a rectangle would work just as well as an image if what you're asking about is why things are being drawn at the wrong coordinates.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan, I'll give that a go when I can, was just wondering if there was anything glaringly obvious that I missed, my first time using Tkinter

Comment: You shows how it looks after return - but you didn't show what result you expect. I don't know which elements are moved. Maybe create separated canvases and replace canvases instead of items on single canvas.